# Clarification: What makes 'new' an operator in C++

Tags: c++, new-operator

I actually come from Java side, so am having a little bit of confusion in learning C++.

One thing I've seen is that many tutorials describe `new` as an operator. In Java, I usually use that keyword to instantiate classes, i.e., create objects from the class like this.

```
MyObject mo = new MyObject();
```

I knew that it can also be used to allocate dynamic memory like as with `int* a = new int;` but, I'm not getting why this is called as a operator. Am of the opinion that operators are symbols that are used to perform mathematical operations, that too, in between the operands. However, new isn't used in between operands, as per my basic understanding.

Can anyone please clarify me why this is called as an operator?

Thanks.

Comment: Even in java you use operators that aren't mathematical operators, as the subscript operator `[]`.

Comment: Because the rules say that it is, end of story. `+` allows you to add, `-` allows you to subtract, `delete` allows you to destroy and `new` allows you to create. Each of those 4 provide an operation on a data object, hence the name operator.

Comment: @JBL I forgot that it actually existed, you were right.

Comment: In C+,+ operators can be overloaded per class-type. To make it even more interesting perhaps, a slight distinction is made between global operator new{[]} / delete{[]} in the global namespace (those are default), and specific overloads of operator new{[]} / delete{[]} that are implemented per class type. This can be useful for debug-tracing or specific storage behavior, such as pre-allocation of heap elements.

Comment: An operator doesn't need to be a symbol. C++ could also define the operator as a symbol, e.g. `$` but `new` (and `delete`) make them very readable. `+` and other mathematical operators can be read very intuitively, so no reason to name them `add` or `plus` etc. Also, by naming the operator `new` C++ reads more similar to other languages like Java then it would if it was a symbol like `$`.

Comment: `new` is an operator in Java, too, for the definition of operator used in the C++ standard.  In both languages, it is a prefix operator.  (The specifications of the two languages use somewhat different language.  Don't get hung up by it: `new` in C++ is very similar to `new` in Java.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am of the opinion that operators are symbols that are used to perform mathematical operations, that too, in between the operands

That is true only of binary infix operators. There are also unary operators that take a single operand (numeric negation; logical negation), parenthesized postfix operators (square brackets, parentheses), and parenthesized prefix operators (conversion) in C++.

Considering such multitude of operators in C++, it should come as no surprise that `new` is also an operator. It is a prefix keyword operator that operates on a type name, and produces a pointer to an instance of that type. The operator has several forms, too: in addition to the regular `new`, there is a placement `new` operator, which has a slightly different syntax.

Comment: Why? What makes it operator-ish? Just saying "the standard" might work, though has the feel of a cop-out...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it clarifies me as a beginner to the language.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the distinction between primitives and objects in C++, "operator" has two meanings. The first meaning is close to what you describe in your question: operators perform some specific operation on their primitive arguments like addition or memory allocation as defined by the standard.

But when used with objects, operators work completely different: they call their corresponding member function of the class. For example `!` which does boolean negation of primitives, calls the `bool operator !()` function of an object. File streams in C++ redefine the `!` function to test if an error has occurred in the stream.

`new` is an operator because it similarly [calls a member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) (and can be redefined! Though I've never seen anyone do that).

Answer (score 1):

The semantics of `new` in Java and C++ are actually quite similar.  In both languages, statements like

```
Object o = new Object();  // Java
```

or

```
Object * optr = new Object();  // C++
```

- allocate memory (on the free store) large enough to hold an object of type `Object`
- invoke the constructor of `Object` passing it a pointer to the newly allocated memory as the `this` pointer.

In Java, some more magic happens behind your back but let's put that aside for now.

The semantics for built-in types (primitives in Java) are also not dramatically different.

In Java

```
int[] array = new int[42];
```

allocates memory large enough to hold 42 `int`s and initializes them with 0.

In C++

```
int * array = new int[42];  // not value-initialized
```

also allocates (on the free store) contiguous memory large enough to hold 42 `int`s but does not initialize them.  If you want value-initialization, say so explicitly:

```
int * array = new int[42]();  // initialized to 0
```

The biggest difference is perhaps how these operators are used.  In Java, if we want a new object, we have no chance but calling (perhaps via some indirection through a factory method) `new`.  In C++, we can not only create objects on the free store (heap) but also with so-called automatic storage duration (ie push them on the stack).  In Java, this is only possible with primitive types.

```
int i = 7;  // valid in both languages
std::string name("Mona Lisa");  // valid C++, invalid Java
```

Often times, this is what you should do in C++.  It is a common mistake of programmers who are used to Java and learn C++ to use `new` all over the place where it is really not needed.

Finally, since C++ by default has no garbage collector, if you allocate memory from the free store (using operator `new`), you must also free it again (using operator `delete`) once you need it no longer.

Why are `new` and `delete` called operators?  I don't know.  Does it really matter?  I think it makes sense, especially since you can overload them just like operator `+` or `-`.

The syntax of object creation in C++ used to be a bit messy.  All these are (sometimes) valid but look quite differently:

```cpp
// automatic storage
int a = 7;
std::string name;  // default constructor
std::string name("Mona Lisa");
// free store (bad idea in this case)
std::string * nameptr = new std::string();  // default constructor
std::string * nameptr = new std::string("Mona Lisa");
```

There are a number of rules about which of these notations is valid in which context and if you forget, some rather strange surprises can happen.

Since C++11, we have a unified syntax for object creation using initializer-lists:

```cpp
// automatic storage
int a {7};
std::string name {}  // default constructor
std::string name {"Mona Lisa"};
// free store (bad idea in this case)
std::string * nameptr = new std::string {};  // default constructor
std::string * nameptr = new std::string {"Mona Lisa"};
```

Unfortunately, since the old syntax is still valid, we have now even more alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean to be an operator? In programming languages `operators` are constructs which behave like functions but differ semantically or syntactically from normal functions.

In C++ operators are semantically special in that they can be overloaded and their arguments must match specific requirements. Obviously their syntax is also special.

`new` meets all those requirements.

Comment: What does "behave like functions" mean if neither the syntax nor semantics are the same?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, that wording is certainly bad. "Behave like functions" is supposed to mean that a combination of a name and a set of arguments yield some results. They don't obey the general rules of function syntax and their semantics are different in respect to overloading.

Comment: functions can be overloaded too. That is not a special feature of only operators. In fact, some operators such as the `&&` operator behave more function-like if they are overloaded (in the case of && it loses the ability to short-circuit).

Comment: @YoungJohn I never said that normal functions cannot be overloaded. Operators are just special when it comes to overloading. You cannot have arbitrary arguments etc.

Comment: @pmr there are numerous operators that also cannot be overloaded, including `.` `sizeof()` and `::`

Answer (score 0):

C++ isn't Java. In Java operators cannot be overloaded.

In C++ they can and there is a syntax to do so. To overload `new` in C++ you use the word `operator` before it. There is also `operator new[]` which can be overloaded.

I presume it makes it stand out as not being a function, even though it might look like one, i.e. it takes arguments of a size and returns void *.

You can overload class member `new` and `delete` too as well as `new[]` and `delete[]`. (Strangely `operator new` for a class still takes as an argument a number of bytes, which seems strange as it has to be the size of the class, so you might think it could be implied).